# PHPReport and Stored Procedure

Tags: php

I'm trying to run my PHPReport script with my Stored Procedure Results, everything seems okay but i'm getting not getting results in my view the code is below

```
<?php
include '@ConnectDB.php' ;
include './includes/PHPReport.php';


        $inCucode   = "GLLL01";               
        $inProdCode =  "71MRT18818W";   
        $inBuyNum    = "NONS01"; 

        // Prepare Stored Procedure call //
        $proc = 'CALL WLKLIB.DSH3518SQ(?,?,?)';
        $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $proc) or die("db2_prepare failed " . db2_stmt_error(). " and " .db2_stmt_errormsg());
        db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, 'inCucode', DB2_PARAM_IN,DB2_CHAR);
        db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, 'inProdCode', DB2_PARAM_IN,DB2_CHAR);
        db2_bind_param($stmt, 3, 'inBuyNum', DB2_PARAM_IN,DB2_CHAR);
        db2_execute($stmt);
        while (db2_fetch_row($stmt)) {
            $Fld2 =  db2_result($stmt, 1);
            $Fld1  = db2_result($stmt, 0);
            $Fld3 =  db2_result($stmt, 2);
            $Fld4 =  db2_result($stmt, 3);
            $Fld5 =  db2_result($stmt, 4);
            $Fld6 =  db2_result($stmt, 5);
            $Fld7 =  db2_result($stmt, 6);
            $Fld8 =  db2_result($stmt, 7);
            $Fld9 =  db2_result($stmt, 8);
            $Fld10 =  db2_result($stmt, 9);
            $Fld11 =  db2_result($stmt, 10);
            $Fld12 =  db2_result($stmt, 11);
            $Fld13 =  db2_result($stmt, 12);

            //Create new PHPReport object
            $R=new PHPReport();

            $R->load(array(
                'id'=>'product',
                'header'=>array(
                    'SKU','Customer Code','Discontinued', 'Available Quantity','Lead Time','Last Order Quanity','Daily Demand','Days on Hand','PO Last Issued Date','PO Quantity','Price','Product Description','Company Code'
              ),

               'config'=>array(
                   0=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'right'),
                   1=>array('width'=>100,'align'=>'left'),
                   2=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'left'),
                   3=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'left'),
                   4=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'left'),
                   5=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'left'),
                   6=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'left'),
                   7=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'left'),
                   8=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'left'),
                   9=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'left'),
                   10=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'left'),
                   11=>array('width'=>200,'align'=>'left'),
                   12=>array('width'=>120,'align'=>'left'),
                   ),
                'data'=>array(
                    array($Fld2),
                    array($Fld1),
                    array($Fld3),
                    array($Fld4),
                    array($Fld5),
                    array($Fld6),
                    array($Fld7),
                    array($Fld8),
                    array($Fld9),
                    array($Fld10),
                    array($Fld11),
                    array($Fld12),
                    array($Fld13)
                ),
            )

          );
            echo $R->render();
            exit();
        }
  ?>
```

I'm i missing anything, why i'm i not getting any results in my view, the page is just blank no errors nothing. I troubleshooted and it came down to the 'db2_execute($stmt);' doesn't run it fails. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Add a try/catch block in your PDO operations to be able to catch the exception and see the `$exception->getMessage()` result.

Comment: I tried that, but still get the same results. nothing just a blank page

Comment: Hey i got the problem solved it was a database error.